# Diameter of the cycle $C_m$

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show that:

The diameter of the cycle $C_m$ is given by

diam($C_m$) $= \begin{cases}\frac{m}{2} \text{if }m \text{ is even}\\
\frac{m-1}{2} \text{if }m \text{ is odd} \end{cases}$

I tried to show this using induction, since it's true for the base cases $n=2$ and $n=3$.
Now, if I assume that it is true for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ - let's first assume that $m$ is odd. Then the largest distance is $\frac{m-1}{2}$. Having a odd number of vertices $m \geq 3$ we know that there are $m$ vertices as well. So there are two vertices such that the path between them is $\frac{m-1}{2}$. But there is another "path" which takes one edge more (since $m$ is odd). Adding an additional vertix (hence $C_{m+1}$) results in $\frac{m}{2}$.

Can anyone help me to improve the proof? Or to try it with another way?

Comment: You should use the term "cyclic graph" instead of "cycle".

Comment: @JeanMarie A cyclic graph is a graph that contains a cycle. OP is referring specifically to the [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph)

Comment: @Giorgos Giapitzakis You are right. Thanks. I hadn't paid attention to this difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reason like this.

Let the vertices of the cycle $C_m$ be labeled $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$.

Between any two vertices $i < j$, there is a path of length $j-i$
and of length $m-(j-i)$.

The shorter of
these paths can be at most $m/2$ if $m$ is even and $(m-1)/2$ if $m$ is odd.